# put json data to a variable in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

This is my project so far--->http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/2/
Observe the var data in the code.For testing purpose I am using only few records.In reality I have around 89k records.

I have a json file named content.json.This is exactly how it goes:--

```
["51b59c162de88", [["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]
["51b59c1b4f52f", [["star-speak", 0.0, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]
["51b59c2bdd5c5", [["signature", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]
["51b59c10ca18f", [["parties", 0.0, 0.017]]]
["51b59c15913b6", [["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]
["51b59c2635997", [["fashion", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011], ["royal-challenge", 0.002, 0.006]]]
["51b59c1a94870", [["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]
["51b59c2844bcf", [["royal-challenge", 0.0077, 0.023]]]
["51b59c2d92798", [["signature", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]
["51b59c19aaa7f", [["parties", 0.0, 0.011], ["fashion", 0.0, 0.006]]]
["51b59c18ec68d", [["parties", 0.0, 0.028]]]
```

I want to load the content of this json file without disturbing the output..How do I put this data in to variable.Putting 89K records in my script will be insane.So how do I get rid of this problem.

Comment: Use AJAX to load the JSON data?

Comment: I want to load json data in to my script.How can i use ajax in this?

Comment: a) Your file is not valid JSON. There are multiple arrays in there, so standard JSON parser will fail. b) Do you really need all entries at once? Else build an AJAX solution, that just transfers the required entries.

Comment: @Dogbert:just have a look at my code.You will realise what my actual problem is.
observe the format of var data.

Comment: You will kill browser if you try to render table with 89K rows. You need grid with paging support.

Comment: @Dogbert:there are around 89k entries like this.Actually ,i got this readymade json file from my senior who used some python for getting this data in such wierd json format.I have been facing the same problem that you mentioned.just for testing purpose,i will load around 100 values and then when everything works fine,i will try the file with 10k records.I dont know how to get rid of this problem now..

Comment: @Tommi:paging support??never came across it..

Comment: One of many implementations: http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/paging/jsonpaging Of course you'll need server-side script which will send partial json. It's not so hard.

Comment: @Tommi:i saw some paging,but i am not able get it.do i have to include some code, view and controller in my script to do this paging stuff.

Comment: It depends on implementation you'll choose. Not all js grids based on MVC (thanks God). Here is a good overview http://flarnie.com/2013/javascript/best-javascript-grids/ ; and as I already said, you will need to send json partially, I guess there is a lot of samples how to do it in any language. Finally, you will need to format your file to valid JSON. Sample you provided at least missing comma between entries.

Comment: Exactly,it is wierd..so wierd that i have trouble saying it as json.
how do i convert this in to proper js format then??so are you trying to say that the mistake is in creation of this json file and this thing in short is collection of arrays?

Comment: @Tommi:I am little new to json.I have decide that I will go back to my php code and render the required js format.
Can you just give me a snippet of what format this json is needed in so that minimal tweaking is to be done in the main code? 
a basic jsfiddle would do...never used json before!!!

Comment: It looks like jsfiddle is down. I recommend to stick to simple array of key-value map as `[ { "key1": "a", "key2": "b"}, { "key1": "a", "key2": "c" } ]`

Comment: @Tommi:but if you look at this line------------["51b59c2635997", [["fashion", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011], ["royal-challenge", 0.002, 0.006]]]

Comment: So? I don't even know what this format means. You should discuss it with guy who send data to you.

Comment: @Tommi:Basically,for tracking hits. "51b59c2635997"==session id... "fashion","parties","royal-challenge"==heading in table(fields in website)......... 0.002(i.e first parameter after fashion)-->indicates hit... 0.006(i.e second parameter after fashion)-->indicates hit

Comment: Then this is too complex structure to properly show it as flat table. You'll obvioulsy will reformat it. In your fiddle you show only one of multiple values of "hit" (you show only 0.2 from `0.002,0.2`). Noone can answer how do _you_ want it to see.

Comment: @Tommi:the thing is only second parameter(0.2) is important and is to be shown inside the box..the first parameter(0.002)...but both of them are to be mentioned in json.

Comment: So do `{ "star-speak": 0.006, "parties": 0.011 }` from `["51b59c1b4f52f", [["star-speak", 0.0, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]` and so on.

Comment: ok..we are quite close..but session id should be present which will determine the fields and hit

Comment: So add it as "ssid":"whdvcwjhgcvjwe" pair. Please, read something about javascript and json in particular. Your questions is VERY basic.

Comment: ok,thank you,i understood some thing about json today!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can do it directly from D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) if you have it in a file:

```
d3.json("your_file.json", function(json) {
     // do stuff   
});
```

**Although**, you should note the comment that states that your data isn't valid JSON. D3.js won't be able to properly handle it in that case.

Comment: I just realised that your question is a duplicate of many other similar questions here in SO. The D3.js tag needs a cleanup ASAP...

Comment: Can I ask why my answer is no longer valid?

Answer (score 0):

Use an AJAX call to load it from your server. Here's a jQuery implementation:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON( "content.json", function(data) {

    // Do stuff with your data here.

  });
});
<script>
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer,buti think you dint see my code,i am using javascript.

Comment: jQuery _is_ Javascript. If you prefer you could code this with an xmlHTTPRequest object.

Comment: the way I am using it is i am putting up all my data in a variable,if i do it by your method..can you guide me what changes have to be made in my code to render the same output.I have never tried jquery,thats why I was mentioned its javascript

Comment: With an AJAX call your data is loaded directly into in a single variable. In my example here the `data` argument contains the data received from the server. You should be able to move your code that creates the table into the function where I've marked `// Do your stuff here` with minimal modification. However, your script for rendering 89k rows in a table will take a long time . As Tommi said - you need some paging support for this.

Comment: :i havent come across paging in the past,i am going through it now,but if possible can you give me a small fiddle about loading data via ajax,the entire code is done in the above link...